JS script in R Shiny App works properly R Studio but not Visual Code
I'm testing a multiscript Shiny app in R. There are 4 scripts:
The app.R:
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(leaflet)
source('myUI.R', local = TRUE)
source('myServer.R')
options(shiny.port = 5001) 

shinyApp(
  ui = myUI,
  server = myserver
)

The UI (myUI.R)
myUI <- shinyUI({fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(src="script.js")),
  leafletOutput("map")
)})

The test script.js
This should just change the size of the leaflet map
setTimeout(function() {
    var mapContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-container')[0];
    mapContainer.style.height = '5vh';
}, 1000);

The Server (myServer.R)
source('leaflet.R', local= TRUE)
myserver <- function(input,output,session){
  output$map1 <- map1
}

and The leaflet.R
map1 <- renderLeaflet({
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
    setView(lng = 0, lat = 0, zoom = 2) 
})

When I run the app.R from R Studio, this all works perfectly whether I use R Studio's browser or open the address in firefox or chrome:
enter image description here
When I run from Visual Code, and open the address in firefox or chrome (I'm just typing http://127.0.0.1:5001 into the URL bar), the script.js doesn't change the size of the leaflet map:
enter image description here
If I don't clear my browser's cache between running the app.R in R Studio and then in Visual Code, the js successfully changes the leaflet map. Am I missing some key step with server that R studio automates??
The js should change the size of the leaflet map. This works if the app.R is run from R studio, but not from Visual Code.
